# Elasticsearch 1.7 Document type aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I'm trying to get an aggregation of the document types in our date store. Looking at the [1.7 Type Filter documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/query-dsl-type-filter.html), its as simple using a type filter. However, I run into the following issue trying to submit that query:

```
curl -XGET localhost:9200/my_index/_search?pretty -d '
{ "type":
  { "value" : "my_type" }
}'
```

Results in:

```
"error" : "SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase [query], all shards failed;...
```

I have success running the following:

```
curl -XGET localhost:9200/my_index/_search?pretty -d '
{ 
  "aggs": {
    "type_a_total": {
      "filter": {
        "type": {
          "value": "type_a"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'

curl -XGET localhost:9200/my_index/_search?pretty -d '
{ 
  "aggs": {
    "type_b_total": {
      "filter": {
        "type": {
          "value": "type_b"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

Results in:

```
...
"aggregations" : {
  "type_a" : {
    "doc_count" : 123456789
  }
}
...
"aggregations" : {
  "type_b" : {
    "doc_count" : 987654321
  }
}
...
```

Any idea how I can get them all back in a single aggregation based on `_type`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to wrap the `type` filter inside a `query` element, either via a `constant_score` query or a `filtered` query (my choice).

```
curl -XGET localhost:9200/my_index/_search?pretty -d '{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "type": {
          "value": "my_type"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

However, if you simply want to get the number of documents of each type, you can simply use a `terms` aggregation on the `_type` field

```
curl -XGET localhost:9200/my_index/_search?pretty -d '{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "all_types": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "_type"
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

Comment: The second query is exactly what I was looking for! FWIW, the first query returned an error. Thank you!